# ssh-copy-id does not update authorized_keys file

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, synology, ssh-keygen, dsm

I can't configure ssh key on my Synology NAS.
File `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is not created or not updated.

**On remote machine (NAS):**

```
$ cd
$ chmod 700 .
$ chmod 700 .ssh
$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

I updated `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to uncomment lines:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

I restarted sshd:

```
$ sudo synoservicectl --reload sshd
```

**On local machine:**

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "myemail@domain.com"
# key generated in custom location 'id_synology'

$ ssh-copy-id -i id_synology -f -p 2222 user1@192.168.1.2
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "id_synology.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: line 251: warning: here-document at line 251 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: line 250: warning: here-document at line 250 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: line 260: EOF: command not found
user1@192.168.1.2's password:

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh -p '2222' 'user1@192.168.1.2'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

On remote machine `authorized_keys` is not updated. I tried without `authorized_keys`, but file is not created. I also tried with rsa algorithm, with or without passphrase, but I have same result.

Any ideas? Or any logs to check why key is not copied?

Comment: Do you have the executable *tr* installed on your local system where you're invoking *ssh-copy-id*?

Comment: Yes :) `which tr` => `/usr/bin/tr`. I am on Windows 10 with Cmder console.